# File does not exist - ExplorerBrowser from WindowsApiCodePack

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set a default-folder when I open my ExplorerBrowser.

```
if (Direcory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    var folderPathFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(folderPath);
     Eb.ExplorerBrowserControl.Navigate(folderPathFile);
}
```

Funny thing that the method throws an "FileNotFoundException" even if Directory.Exists returns true.

The FromFilePath-Method looks like:

```
internal ShellFile(string path)
    {
        // Get the absolute path
        string absPath = ShellHelper.GetAbsolutePath(path);

        // Make sure this is valid
        if (!File.Exists(absPath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The given path does not exist ({0})", path));

        ParsingName = absPath;
        Path = absPath;
    }
```

I'm not quite sure what "GetAbsolutePath(path)" does, but my path already is absolute. Does it maybe destroy my functional path by calling this method? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: GetAbsolutePath will return C:\... etc, rather than a relative or virtual path. Does the account under which the application runs have permission to access this location? Without permissions, a File.Exists() call will return false, which will cause the FileNotFound exception to be raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folderPath variable, when passed to Directory.Exists() returns true, so this is a directory path (file paths passed to this method return false).

This same value is passed into ShellFile.FromFilePath(), the absolute value of the path is obtained, and this is then passed into File.Exists -- but, as above, it is a directory path, hence false is returned.